# Change password form not working in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to build a simple web app, which has a form to change one's password. I am using werkzeug.security functions (check_password_hash and generate_password_hash) to do so. This two functions work perfectly in during registering and logging in. But for some reason, when I change password, the password just doesn't match. I even wrote a code to check the password right away, `passwordChange = check_password_hash(newHash, newPassword)`, then `print(f'\n\n{passwordChange}\n\n')`but for some reason it always returned false. Here is the full code. Any response is greatly appreciated :)

FLASK

```
@app.route("/passwordchange", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def changepassword():
    """"Change users' password"""
    if request.method == "POST":
        newPassword = request.form.get("newPassword")
        newConfirmation = request.form.get("newConfirmation")

        # Ensure that the user has inputted
        if (not newPassword) or (not newConfirmation):
            return apology("Please fill all of the provided fields!", 400)

        # Check to see if password confirmation were the same or not
        if newPassword != newConfirmation:
            return apology("password did not match with password (again)", 400)

        user_id = session["user_id"]
        newHash = generate_password_hash("newPassword")

        db.execute("UPDATE users SET hash = ? WHERE id = ?", newHash, user_id)
        passwordChange = check_password_hash(newHash, newPassword)

        print(f'\n\n{passwordChange}\n\n')
        return redirect("/login")
    else:
        return render_template("password.html")
```

HTML

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Change Password
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/passwordchange" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="newConfirmation" placeholder="New Password (again)" type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Change Password</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Don't you generate a new hash each time from a const string `"newPassword"` instead of the variable `newPassword`?

Comment: So, how can I fix it? Because I am still confused.

Comment: `newHash = generate_password_hash(newPassword)` instead of `newHash = generate_password_hash("newPassword")`.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Yeah, that worked!, thanks!